# Google sheets formula for returning multiple text values

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I am trying to write a formula to return one of three categories based on text contained in a code in an adjacent column.

- NC = Non Credible
- CCC or COA = Credible
- OP = Open

So, if E1 is NC201707/03, D1 is Non Credible

I tried the following formula but it did not work.

`IFS(E1="*NC*", "Non credible", E1="*CCC*", "Credible", E1="*COA*", "Credible", E1="*OP*", "Open")`

Example content for the columns would be as follows. Thanks!

```
Column E
NC201707/03
NC201707/10
CC201605/01
OP201802/01

Column D
Non Credible
Non Credible
Credible
Open
```

Help much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `E1="*NC*"`, you check if the value in E1 is **exactly** `*NC*`.
To see if there is NC in the value without it matching exactly, you will need to use `REGEXMATCH`.

It works this way: `REGEXMATCH(text, regular_expression)` (https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292)

So your formula would look like something:
`IFS(REGEXMATCH(E1, "NC"), "Non credible", REGEXMATCH(E1, "CCC"), "Credible", REGEXMATCH(E1, "COA"), "Credible", REGEXMATCH(E1, "OP"), "Open")`

(You'll probably have to change the regex, I didn't try them)

Comment: Thanks, I removed them!

Answer (score 0):

thy this

`=IF(IFERROR(FIND("CCC",E13,1),0),"Credible",IF(IFERROR(FIND("NC",E13,1),0),"Non Credible",IF(IFERROR(FIND("OP",E13,1),0),"OPEN",IF(IFERROR(FIND("COA",E13,1),0),"Credible","New"))))`

Should work

Answer (score 0):

The results you show for the sample data may be achieved for both Excel and Google Sheets with, in D1:

```
=IF(LEFT(E1)="N","Non-Credible",IF(LEFT(E1)="C","Credible","Open"))
```

copied down to suit.

The above is not necessarily the best solution for either Excel or Sheets.